# Chai test array of objects to "contain something like" an object submatch

Tags: javascript, chai

Ok. I've tried to read other questions here but still didn't find a straightforward answer.

How can I assert a partial object match in an array using chai? 
Something like the following:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var data = [ { name: 'test', value: 'bananas' } ];
expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.contains.somethig.like({name: 'test'});
```

Just to clarify, my intention is to get as close to the example provided as possible.

- to chain after the `.be.an('array')` and
- to provide only the partial object as a parameter (unlike [chai-subset](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-subset/)).

I really thought that `expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.deep.contains({name: 'test'});` would work, but it fails on not being a partial match and I'm kinda screwed there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [`chai-like@0.2.14`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-like) the following approch will work:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(require('chai-like'));
chai.use(require('chai-things')); // Don't swap these two

expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.contains.something.like({name: 'test'});
```

Comment: The order that you ```use``` the chai plugins is indeed important; getting them the right way around solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

### ES6+

Clean, functional and without dependencies, simply use a map to filter the key you want to check

something like:

```
const data = [ { name: 'test', value: 'bananas' } ];
expect(data.map(e=>e.name)).to.include("test");
```

and if you want to test multiple keys:

```
expect(data.map(e=>({name:e.name}))).to.include({name:"test"});
```

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: Nice and clean. Although it works for single property (`name` in this case) only. For two or more, you'd have to repeat your singleliner for each. `chai-like` compares all properties of the passed object, while ignoring the rest of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you dismissed `chai-subset` as this seems to work:

```
expect(data).to.be.an("array").to.containSubset([{ name: "test" }]);
```

Comment: Well, I must admit I simply don't like the `containSubset` naming and the extra brackets. I was hoping to find a solution purely using `chai` without plugins, but I guess that is not the case. I tried to dig a bit into `.contains.something.like({...})` version (using both `chai-things` and `chai-like`), which I love for sounding so natural, and I thing I've found [why](https://github.com/zation/chai-like/pull/12) it [wasn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41726208/336753) at the first place. I know.. two plugins instead of one, but I just like the phrasing and the simpler parameter more.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without third libraries or plugins:

```
var data = [ { name: 'test', value: 'bananas' } ];
expect(data.map(({name}) => ({name})).to.deep.include({name: 'test'});
```