# Chai - Testing for boolean values in an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

So I'm trying to test for the values of Boolean property in an array of object. Currently I'm using this code which doesn't seem to work.

```
describe('/GET/deleted', () => {
    it('should get all objects that are deleted', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/api/object/deleted')
            .set('Cookie', cookie)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.be.a('array');
                expect(res.body).to.have.deep.property('[0].deleted', true);
                done();
            });
    });
})
```

How would you test for the values of a boolean property in an array of objects. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44677002/336753), this will make sure each object in the array contains a property `deleted` equal to `true`.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(require('chai-things'));

var data = [{deleted:true, other:'stuff'}, {deleted:true, more:'thigns'}];

expect(data).all.have.property('deleted', true);
```