# Test array of objects for values equal to values from another array in Chai

Tags: javascript, tdd, chai

I'm totally new to Chai, and this is probably really simple, but I can't find any reference to my case in the official docs. I'm trying to verify that an array with two objects has a property value exactly matching values in another array.

Consider the following:

```
test('Array includes ids', function() {
    const array1 = [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            id: '1'
        },
        {
            type: 'type2',
            id: '2'      
        },
    ]
        
    const array2 = ['1', '2']
    
    chai.expect(array1).to.have.deep.members(array2) // fails
})
```

I'd like to verify that objects in `array1` has an `id` property with one of the values found in `array2`. I know I could map `array1` as `array1.map(p => p.id)` and compare that with `array2`, but that seems to go against testing as a practice. After all, I don't want to tamper too much with my target to make it conform to my current level of knowledge.

Is there a better way to test this? (Needless to say, my example code above does not work as desired.)

Comment: personally array1.map (p => p.id) seems to me to be the answer. On the other hand, what seems incorrect to me is the name of your test. I'm thinking of something like: Array elements include id.

Comment: I am not sure you can directly test via this.

Comment: can you please your error stack trace for more clarification of problem

Comment: No need for stack trace, It's pretty obvious why it fails

Comment: Thank's for helping out folks. I did find a neat [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100356/182048). Unfortunately I'm using Postman and it seems they're not importing chai-like nor chai-things. So I guess I'll accept the current answer, although I'm not happy about the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform your `array1` with `.map()` method to have your kind of array with only ids in it just like `array2`,

```
test('Array includes ids', function() {
    const array1 = [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            id: '1'
        },
        {
            type: 'type2',
            id: '2'      
        },
    ]
        
    const arr1 = array1.map(e=>e.id);//transform with .map() -> ['1', '2']
    const array2 = ['1', '2']
    
    chai.expect(arr1).to.have.deep.members(array2) // pass
})
```

Comment: I think this he already mentioned. He doesn't want to do like. He already know he can do this

Comment: Also .deep is not required here